Agora Call Fails on AWS with "AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid token, authorized failed
We are encountering an issue with Agora RTC integration when running on AWS. The same code works perfectly in the local environment but fails on AWS with the following error:
Agora-SDK [ERROR]: [client-29004] join number: 1, Joining channel failed, rollback AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: flag: 4096, message: AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid token, authorized failed
    at vt (...js:1:586450)
    at ...js:1:583880
    at async ...js:1:187640

What we’ve tried so far:

Hardcoded channelName and UID to ensure dynamic values are not causing the issue.

Validated the implementation locally, and it works perfectly without errors.
Observations:
The issue appears specific to our AWS environment.
Tokens are generated on the backend and work fine locally.
Outbound network access to Agora’s signaling servers has been configured (e.g., port 443 for HTTPS).
Environment Details:
Agora SDK Version: [Please specify]
AWS Setup: [Fargate/ECS/EC2] in a [Public/Private Subnet].
Network Configuration: Security group allows outbound traffic to all destinations (0.0.0.0/0) on port 443.
Question:
What could be causing the "AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid token, authorized failed" error in the AWS environment specifically?
Are there any additional network or token validation steps required for deployments on AWS?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
const token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(
appID,
appCertificate,
channelName,
uid,
role,
privilegeExpiredTs
);


Thank you!
